# Running AnnotationConfigApplicationContext from Spring Test

Tags: java, spring

My test class is annotated with the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestLocalPersisterConfiguration.class })
@ActiveProfiles(EnvironmentProfile.TEST_LOCAL)
public class MyTestClass {
  // run someMethod here that loads AnnotationConfigApplicationContext in Java class
}
```

From the test class I run a method from the primary class and try to load the AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`:

```
// Java class method that is run from test class    
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestLocalPersisterConfiguration.class, ProdPersisterConfiguration.class);
GCThreadStopRepository repository = applicationContext.getBean(GCThreadStopRepository.class);
```

However, Spring is complaining `No qualifying bean of type [ca.nbc.data.sql.repository.GCThreadStopRepository] is defined`

I am not sure why this is happening nor how to resolve this.

The `GCThreadStopRepository` is annotated with `@Repository`.

`TestLocalPersisterConfiguration` extends `GenericPersisterConfiguration`, which has the following to scan and load bean definitions:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
  String persistenceUnitName = environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
  final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
  emfBean.setPersistenceUnitName(persistenceUnitName);
  emfBean.setPackagesToScan("ca.nbc.data.sql");
  emfBean.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml");
  emfBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
  if(getJpaProperties() != null) {
    emfBean.setJpaProperties(getJpaProperties());
  }
  return emfBean;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have found that when the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` is initiated in the Java class, the `@ActiveProfiles(EnvironmentProfile.TEST_LOCAL)` setting from the test class is not propagated to the Java class, ie. a run of `applicationContext.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles()` in the Java class return an empty array.

Is there a way to propagate the `@ActiveProfiles(EnvironmentProfile.TEST_LOCAL)` to be system wide?

Comment: Why on earth are you loading it yourself? You seem to be missing the point of the `@ContextConfiguration` and spring based test classes. Next to that Spring uses proxy based app so if your `GCThreadStopRepository` implements an interface it will be only available as those interfaces not the concrete class (that is hidden inside a proxy).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't initialize the application context yourself, you actually already have it once you use @ContextConfiguration

all you need to do is:

```
@Autowired
GCThreadStopRepository repository;
```

you just need to make sure the bean is defined in a @Configuration class that you scan  - either by defining it in:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {YourClass.class})
```

or in the @Configuration class itself - @ComponentScan for @Component or @Import to add another @Configuration class

in order to use ActiveProfiles you need to define @Profile on your classes. if a class doesn't have @Profile defined - it will be active in all profiles. only classes that define @Profile will be included/excluded in the scan - according to the profile.
so this is not the problem. 
you need to add

```
@ComponentScan("ca.nbc.data.sql.repository")
```

in TestLocalPersisterConfiguration - that will scan the package and read the @Repository

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` in the Java class in the `main` method is not written by me but by another developer. He runs this method from the test class. I actually realized that the issue is because the `@ActiveProfiles` I set in the test class is not propagated to the primary class, is there a way to propagate `@ActiveProfiles` set from a Spring test class to be system wide?